# AWS RDS ORACLE DBMS_SCHEDULER to run a purgue every minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds

I want to use the ORACLE DBMS_SCHEDULER on my AWS RDS ORACLE

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.Scheduler.html

to do the following command every minute:

```
delete from MYTABLE.RECEIVED_TOKEN where EXPIRY_DATE < systimestamp and rownum <= 1;
commit;
exit
```

can I do that with this scheduler? I want to avoid the possibility to use a Lambda if it is possible.

I don´t understand too much about how it works or if I can schedule something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know AWS.

---

As this is an Oracle database, use its scheduling capabilities. How? "Convert" that `delete` statement into a stored procedure which will then be scheduled by (older and somewhat simpler) `DBMS_JOB` or (modern, improved and more complex) `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.

Here's example.

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_del_rt
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     DELETE FROM received_token
  5           WHERE     expiry_date < SYSTIMESTAMP
  6                 AND ROWNUM <= 1;
  7
  8     COMMIT;
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Daily job which runs at 02:00 (2 past midnight):

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  3        job_name    => 'delete_received_token',
  4        job_type    => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5        job_action  => 'BEGIN p_del_rt; end;',
  6        start_date  =>
  7           TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('10.01.2023 02:00 Europe/Zagreb',
  8                            'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
  9        repeat_interval  =>
 10           'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN; BYHOUR=2; BYMINUTE=0',
 11        enabled     => TRUE,
 12        comments    => 'Delete rows whose expiry date is less than "right now"');
 13  END;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What is it set to?

```
SQL> SELECT job_action,
  2         TO_CHAR (next_run_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') next_run_date
  3    FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS
  4   WHERE job_name = 'DELETE_RECEIVED_TOKEN';

JOB_ACTION           NEXT_RUN_DATE
-------------------- -------------------
BEGIN p_del_rt; end; 11.02.2023 02:00:00

SQL>
```

---

So that we wouldn't wait until tomorrow, I'll run the job manually. This is table contents *before* (dates are in `DD.MM.YYYY` format) (today is `10.02.2023`, which means that `ID = 1` and `ID = 2` have `expiry_date` less than *today*):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM received_token;

        ID EXPIRY_DATE
---------- ------------
         1 23.12.2022
         2 28.01.2023
         3 13.08.2023

SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job ('delete_received_token');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Table contents *after*:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM received_token;

        ID EXPIRY_DATE
---------- ------------
         2 28.01.2023
         3 13.08.2023

SQL>
```

---

Apparently, it *works*. Though, I'm not sure what you meant to say by using the following condition:

```
and rownum <= 1
```

Why do you want to restrict number of rows deleted to (at most) one? (it'll be *zero* if no row's `expiry_date` is less than `systimestamp`). Without that condition, both `ID = 1` and `ID = 2` rows would have been deleted.

No problem with me, just saying.

Comment: Nice and very complete answer! thank you very much. Let me do a slow read and try it out and I'll be back :)